Does Windows as a host support virtio_vsocket?
Does Windows (as a host) and Hyper-v support virtio_tansport( virtio_vsocket)?
If supported, what are the advantages of hyperv_transport(hv_socket) over virtio_tansport(virtio_vsocket)?
How to select whether to use virtio_transport or hypver_transport? If I am using Hyper-v, can I only choose hyperv_transport, or can I also choose virtio_transport but its performance is poor? If I am using other virtualization platforms (not Hyper-v), can I only choose virtio_transport?
What is the reason why we are developing a new vsocket tranport - hypver_transport?
virtio_tansport and hyperv_transport have different transmission mechanisms, virtio_transport is based on virtio, hyperv_transport is transmitted by VMbus using Windows Virtualization technology stack, when Windows is the host and Linux/Android is the guest, how to secect virtio_transport or hyperv_transport for vsocket in the guest?
Does hyper-v and Windows support virtio_transport or only support hyperv_transport?
